# Firebase Auth error/argument-error on Next.js Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication

I am working on a personal project using Next.js, Typescript, and Firebase for the auth and db. I am trying to do a sign in page with Google and it's giving me an error. The error is `auth/argument-error`. On the [docs of firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Error) it says this about the error:
*Thrown if a method is called with incorrect arguments.* I read that it could be related to the firebaseconfig file that may have wrong keys, but the login with email and password works fine.

This is the firebaseconfig.ts

```
import { initializeApp, type FirebaseOptions } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { GoogleAuthProvider, initializeAuth } from 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig: FirebaseOptions = {
    apiKey: XXXXXX,
    authDomain: XXXXX,
    projectId: xxxx,
    storageBucket: xxxx,
    messagingSenderId: xxxxx,
    appId: xxxxx,
    measurementId: xxxxx,
};


const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
const auth = initializeAuth(app);
const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
export { auth, googleProvider };

export default app;
```

This is where I have the signup component where I have the logic of the error:

```
import { GoogleAuthProvider, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, onAuthStateChanged, sendEmailVerification, sendPasswordResetEmail, signInWithPopup } from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth, db, googleProvider } from '../../../firebase/firebaseConfig';
import { doc, setDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import GoogleIcon from '../../Atoms/svg-icons/ico__google';
import Modal from '../../Molecules/Modal';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const SignUpComponent = () => {

    const router = useRouter();

    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        name: '',
        address: '',
        mobile: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
    });
    const { name, address, mobile, email, password } = formData;

    const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
        try {
            setLoading(true);
            const userCredential = await signInWithPopup(auth, googleProvider);

            const user = userCredential.user;
            console.log('user', user);

            if (user) {
                const userRef = doc(db, 'users', user.uid);
                await setDoc(userRef, {
                    name: user.displayName,
                    email: user.email,
                    blocked: false,
                });

                router.push('/admin');
            }

            setLoading(false);
        } catch (error: any) {
            console.log('error', error);
            const errorCode = error.code;
            const errorMessage = error.message;
            console.log('errorCode', errorCode);
            console.log('errorMessage', errorMessage);

            setLoading(false);
        }
    };

    const onSubmit = async (e: any) => {

        try {
            const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);

            // Send verification email
            await sendEmailVerification(userCredential.user);

            const user = userCredential.user;
            if (user) {
                const userRef = doc(db, 'users', user.uid);
                await setDoc(userRef, {
                    name: name,
                    address: address,
                    mobile: mobile,
                    email: email,
                    blocked: false,
                });
            }

            setLoading(false);

            setShowModal(true);
        } catch (error: any) {
            console.log('error', error);
            const errorCode = error.code;
            const errorMessage = error.message;

            setFormData({ name: '', address: '', mobile: '', email: '', password: '' }); 
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *auth/argument-error* error is coming from this line in **firebaseconfig.ts**.

```
const auth = initializeAuth(app);
```

The initializeAuth function is expecting an additional argument for dependencies.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#initializeauth

For example:

```
const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
  persistence: browserSessionPersistence,
  popupRedirectResolver: undefined,
});
```

However, the docs recommend getAuth instead of intializeAuth, unless you have specific requirements.

> In general, getAuth is the easiest way to initialize Auth and works
> for most use cases. Use initializeAuth if you need control over which
> persistence layer is used, or to minimize bundle size if you're not
> using either signInWithPopup or signInWithRedirect.

In your case the simplest solution would be to replace initializeAuth with getAuth.

**firebaseconfig.ts**

```
import { initializeApp, type FirebaseOptions } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { GoogleAuthProvider, getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig: FirebaseOptions = {
    apiKey: XXXXXX,
    authDomain: XXXXX,
    projectId: xxxx,
    storageBucket: xxxx,
    messagingSenderId: xxxxx,
    appId: xxxxx,
    measurementId: xxxxx,
};


const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
export { auth, googleProvider };

export default app;
```

Comment: Thanks elMarquis! replacing initializeAuth() for getAuth() solve it!